# How to get the range of all continous numbers in an array (increasing subsequence)?

Tags: javascript, ruby

In ruby I can use `chunk_while` as such:

```
a = [1,2,4,9,10,11,12,15,16,19,20,21]
b = a.chunk_while {|i, j| i+1 == j }
p b.to_a #=> [[1, 2], [4], [9, 10, 11, 12], [15, 16], [19, 20, 21]]
```

What is the best way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You could alternatively use Ruby's [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when): `a.slice_when { |x,y| y != x + 1 }.to_a`.

Comment: Another way, which I mention only because it may lend itself to translation to JavaScript is: `a.each_with_object([]) { |x,arr| arr.any? && x == arr.last.last + 1 ? arr.last << x : arr << [x] }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `chunkWhile()` function with `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const chunkWhile = (predicate, arr) =>
  arr.reduce((r, n) => {
    let last = r[r.length - 1]
    
    if(!last || !predicate(last[last.length - 1], n)) {
      last = []
      r.push(last)
    }
    
    last.push(n)
    
    return r
  }, [])

const a = [1,2,4,9,10,11,12,15,16,19,20,21]

const result = chunkWhile((i, j) => i + 1 === j, a)

console.log(result)
```